# Contaminated normals, Multivariate normal distributions and PCA

Tags: normal-distribution

While studying the above mentioned topics, i got a little confused in reading two things. I have two questions. First, in:

[Scanned text 1](http://postimg.org/image/w2ppw629d/)

how exactly P[W <= w] unfolds as seen in the red rectangle?

And secondly:

[Scanned text 2](http://postimg.org/image/8cdwardkv/)

a_i? I suppose this could be a typo. In case not, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding $1$:**
This is the principle of exhaustion. either $I_\epsilon = 1$ or $I_\epsilon = 0$ but not both and not neither. Thus
$$P(\Phi) = P(\Phi|I_\epsilon = 1) + P(\Phi | I_\epsilon = 0)$$
**Regarding $2$:**
This is no typo, it's the inner product
$$a' v_i = a^T v_i = \langle a, v_i \rangle$$
Just some odd notation ($\cdot'$ for the transposed row-vector)
The inner product of two vectors $u,v \in \mathbb R^n$ is defined by
$$\langle u,v \rangle := \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i$$
note the different meaning of $v_i$: here $v_i$ denotes the $i$-th component of the vector $v$ and above $v_i$ is itself a vector

Comment: thank you. Regarding "2", i know that's the inner product notation, but my question is: what a_i (circled red in the figure) stands for in that context?

Comment: That's the $i$-th component of the vector $a$

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll expand on that myself. The last summation is equal to a_i, because, since the basis {v_1,v_2, ..., v_n} is orthonormal, <v_i,v_j> equals to 1 only when j = i.

Comment: Yes, and $0$ otherwise. Btw: use $\text{\$a_i\$}$ to get MathJax: $a_i$